# Gradle failed while updating gradle plugin version from 4.1.1 to 4.2.1 in android

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am updating gradle plugin version from 4.1.1 to 4.2.1 gradle build is getting failed with the below build output.

> Task :app:stripProductionDebugDebugSymbols
> Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libbarhopper_v2.so.

> Task :app:kaptProductionDebugKotlin

> Task :biomobileplus_sdk_android:bundleLibRuntimeToDirProductionDebug

Android studio version : 2020.3.1 patch 3

Gradle version : 6.7.1

Comment: Maybe you're using a dependency which doesn't work with 6.7.1 yet

Comment: No, I am using the same dependency with same gradle version in another project and it is working fine. @gtxtreme

Comment: Clean cache and build again. Remember this whenever something unusual happens xD

Comment: This didn't work in my case. I have uninstall the studio and install it then it works for once again it starts failing.@gtxtreme